# Copy build artifacts to a source set in Gradle multi project build

Tags: gradle

I have a root gradle project consisting of two sub projects:

1. JS frontend bundled by wepback called `admin-frontend`
2. Java Spring backend called `admin-backend`

The build task in `admin-frontend` runs webpack which emits bundles into `admin-frontend/build/resources/static`. The corresponding command in `admin-backend` compiles the Java app.

I need gradle to:

1. Build `admin-frontend`
2. Copy `admin-frontend/build/resources/static` to `admin-backend/src/main/resources/static`
3. Build `admin-backend` so that the build would include the webpack bundles copied in at the 2nd step

How do I go about that?

Here's the directory structure:

```
.
├── admin-backend
│   ├── build
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── src
│       ├── main
│           ├── resources
│               ├── static
├── admin-frontend
│   ├── build
│   │   ├── resources
│   │       ├── static
│   ├── build.gradle
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
└── settings.gradle
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the following task in the root `build.gradle`:

```
task build(dependsOn: ':frontend:webpack') {
    doLast {
        def backendStaticResources = new File(project(':backend').projectDir ,"/src/main/resources/static");
        def backendTemplates = new File(project(':backend').projectDir ,"/src/main/resources/templates");

        [backendStaticResources,backendTemplates].each {
            delete(fileTree(it) {
                exclude '.gitignore'
            })
        }

        copy {
            from file('frontend/build/index.html')
            into 'backend/src/main/resources/templates'
        }

        copy {
            from 'frontend/build'
            into 'backend/src/main/resources/static'
        }
    }
}
```

So first it runs webpack, copies its build into the static resources, builds java.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question. Please don't take this answer as authoritative or even as something that will/can work, but it's something you might want to try.

Start by declaring the static resources as an output — or [*artifact*](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_management.html#sec:artifacts_and_configurations) — of the `admin-frontend` project. You should be able to do that with something like the following:

```
configurations {
    staticFiles
}

artifacts {
    staticFiles file("$buildDir/resources/static"), {
        builtBy build
    }
}
```

I'll be honest, I'm guessing somewhat with the above syntax. Also, you would ideally replace the `file(...)` with the task or list of tasks that actually generate the static files. See the example in the [`ArtifactHandler`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.ArtifactHandler.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.ArtifactHandler:add(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) API documentation.

Now all you need to do is add that configuration as a dependency in the back-end project. Something like:

```
configurations {
    frontEndResources
}

dependencies {
    frontEndResources project(path: ":path:to:admin-frontend", configuration: "staticResources")
}
```

You should then be able to use `configurations.frontEndResources` to incorporate the static resources however you see fit. For example, if you wanted to include them in the project's JAR:

```
jar.from configurations.frontEndResources
```

Ideally you'd be able to configure it as part of the *main* source set's resources, but that only seems to be possible with directories, not collections of files. I think there's a hacky way round that:

1. Create a task that copies the static resources to some custom directory under *$buildDir*
2. Configure that directory as an output of the main source set ([see second example in `SourceSetOutput` API doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetOutput.html)) — make sure you specify that the output is declared as `builtBy` the task from step 1
3. Sit back and watch as Gradle will automatically run the task(s) in `admin-frontend` that generate the static resources, copy those resources to `admin-backend`, and package them into the resulting application. In other words, you should have incremental build working smoothly between `admin-frontend` and `admin-backend`.

Now all that's left to do is see if it actually works :)